# If I have a regex solution for a regex question, but the solution uses features not supported in the OP's regex flavour, should I still answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47578187/5133585).

At first, the OP did not say what flavour of regex are they using, so I came up with a solution that only works if `\K` is supported. Then the OP said that they are using Java regex, so my answer won't work. I edited the answer and added a solution that works in Java, since I did not know what I should do, so I chose the safest option.

Then I thought, wouldn't my original answer be beneficial to future readers if they just so happens to be using a favour that *does* support `\K`? Or, suddenly Java might support `\K` one day (though unlikely).

In general, if I have a solution for a regex question that uses features not supported by the OP's requested flavour, should I still post it?

Comment: This is why I never answer regex questions that don't state upfront which flavor is being used. Like it or not, regex is not one universal standard and every programming language has its own flavor (even if multiple languages share the same flavor, e.g. PCRE, the least an asker could do is say that they're using PCRE).

Comment: IMO in this case you did the right thing; providing a solution that works for OP's flavor of regexes is of paramount importance, but keeping a solution that will help future readers having the same problem but possibly using a different regex engine is great as well (for me in particular, I didn't know about resetting matches :-) ).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the question itself specifies the regex engine being used, then you should only post answers that work in that engine.  If you want to post an answer using an entirely different engine, then *post it as an answer to a question asking about that engine* (creating such a question if none exists, and it's actually a useful and on topic question), rather than posting it on one where it's not a correct answer.

Comment: and then link to it as a "see also related question for FooFlavoured Regex." to help signpost anyone googling who ends up as the wrong one.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to outline both the solutions in a single answer outlining the difference? I mean: For Java [solution].. For some-regex-flavor [solution]

Comment: @o_O No, if the question is asking for a Java solution, then people are going to look at that question and it's answers when they're using a java engine, and aren't interested in solutions for other engines, and people using other engines are going to be looking at questions about those engines, and so are much less likely to see answers on solutions asking about engines they aren't using